# Combine ActiveModel serializer results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I have the following ActiveModel serializer which parses the following data:

```
class CarSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
attributes :brand, :wheels, :events
def brand
  { id: object.id, brand_name: object.brand_name }
end

def wheels
  object.wheel_details
end

def events
  object.car_events
end
end
```

and the following is the data shows up:

```
{
"car_info": [
{
"car": {
"id": 1,
"brand_name": "opel"
},
"wheels": [
{
"id": 2,
"size": "23.4"
},
{
"id": 1,
"size": "22.3"
}
],
"events": [
{
"id": 1,
"event_place": "america"
},
{
"id": 1,
"event_place": "asia"
}
]
```

However, i want the data to look like the following:

```
{
"car_info": [
{
"car": {
"id": 1,
"brand_name": "opel"
},
"wheels_and_events": [
{
"id": 2,
"size": "23.4"
"event_place": "america"
},
{
"id": 1,
"size": "22.3"
"event_place": "asia"
}
]
```

I'm using has_many through associations for 3 tables and one table for the relation.

Comment: How WheelDetail should be merged with CarEvent? What WheelDetail does link to what CarEvent?

Comment: Do you want to merge objects who have the same `id` ? Or objects who have the same index ?

Comment: I want to merge objects to have the same index